# Google API PHP Client Not Saving Contact Address Using V3 API

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

I'm using the Google API PHP Client to interact with the Contacts API and I can get the title, email address, and phone number to save fine.  However, I cannot get the address of a contact to save.  I've compared what's being sent in the request with their documentation here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts and all seems to be the same.

Here's the code for calling the API:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$entry = $doc->createElement('atom:entry');
$entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
$doc->appendChild($entry);

$category = $doc->createElement('atom:category');
$category->setAttribute('scheme', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind');
$category->setAttribute('term', 'http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact');
$entry->appendChild($category);

$title = $doc->createElement('title', $name);
$entry->appendChild($title);

$email = $doc->createElement('gd:email');
$email->setAttribute('rel', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work');
$email->setAttribute('address', $workEmail);
$entry->appendChild($email);

$contact = $doc->createElement('gd:phoneNumber', $workPhone);
$contact->setAttribute('rel', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work');
$entry->appendChild($contact);

$workAddress = $doc->createElement('gd:structuredPostalAddress');
$workAddress->setAttribute('rel', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work');
$entry->appendChild($workAddress);
$workStreet = $doc->createElement('gd:street', $workAddress1);
$workAddress->appendChild($workStreet);
$workPo = $doc->createElement('gd:pobox', $workAddress2);
$workAddress->appendChild($workPo);
$workXmlCity = $doc->createElement('gd:city', $workCity);
$workAddress->appendChild($workXmlCity);
$workXmlState = $doc->createElement('gd:region', $workState);
$workAddress->appendChild($workXmlState);
$workXmlZip = $doc->createElement('gd:postcode', $workZip);
$workAddress->appendChild($workXmlZip);
$wFormatted = $workAddress1 . $workCity;
$workFormatted = $doc->createElement('gd:formattedAddress', $wFormatted);
$workAddress->appendChild($workFormatted);

$xmlToSend = $doc->saveXML();
echo '<p>Making call</p>';

$client = GoogleHelper::getClient();

$req = new \Google_Http_Request('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');
$req->setRequestHeaders(
    array('content-type' => 'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=feed'));
          //,'GData-Version' => '3.0'));
$req->setRequestMethod('POST');
$req->setPostBody($xmlToSend);

$val = $client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($req);
$response = $val->getResponseBody();
```

As you'll see in the above, I've commented out where I've tried to add the GData-Version header as doing so resulted in nothing being saved.

Here's what the request body looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
  <title>address test</title>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" address="work@working.com"/>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work">123-123-1234</gd:phoneNumber>
  <gd:structuredPostalAddress rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work">
    <gd:street>123 Fake St</gd:street>
    <gd:pobox>333</gd:pobox>
    <gd:city>Minneapolis</gd:city>
    <gd:region>MN</gd:region>
    <gd:postcode>55427</gd:postcode>
    <gd:formattedAddress>123 Fake StMinneapolis</gd:formattedAddress>
  </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
</atom:entry>
```

Comment: I tried the above posted code, and I was able to create a contact and contacts address is also saved. Is the address getting saved when you specify the G-data version?

Comment: When I specify the G-data version the contact doesn't get created